# Expected time until absorption in multi absorption states CTMC

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Let $S = \{1, 2, 3, ..., a, b\}$ be a finite set of states, where $a$ and $b$ are the absorption states. The transition probability from state $i$ to $j$ is $P_{ij}$, and the transition rate from state $i$ to state $j$ is $Q_{ij}$.

When we have only one absorption state, we can use the method explained in the answer of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2335355/expected-time-of-absorption-for-time-changed-markov-chain) as the Markov Chain will only absorb in one state. Does anyone have any idea how we can calculate the time until absorption to a specific absorption state when we have more than one state to absorb into?

Comment: What do you mean by "the time until absorption to a specific state"? How is this defined for instances that are absorbed by the other absorbing state?

Comment: Imagen the state set $S$ mentioned above, I want to know the average time the system will take until it absorbs at state $b$, given that $b$ is one of the absorption states.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question (it basically just repeats what was already written in the question). How do you define "the average time the system will take until it absorbs at state $b$" in view of the fact that some instances of the system are absorbed at $a$, not at $b$? Do you average only over those that are absorbed at $b$?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm looking for. I want to know the average time to absorb at $b$ only. in other words, if $a$ is a success state and $b$ is a fail state, I want to get the average time to success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I used, and it matched the simulations, is removing all the transitions that goes to the other absorbing states and keep the ones that goes to the desired state. For example, if we have two absorbing states $a$ and $b$, and we want to calculate the time until absorption at state $b$, we remove all the transitions that goes to $a$ and keep the ones that goes to $b$, then calculate the time until absorption using the method [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2335355/expected-time-of-absorption-for-time-changed-markov-chain).